# Prove : $ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha -\beta} \quad \text{close to 1.}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

If $\alpha \geq |\beta^{1+\eta}|,$ how to prove that-

$$ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha -\beta} \quad \text{close to 1} ?$$

**Attempt:**  If,  $\alpha= |\beta^{1+\eta}|$,

then, $$ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha -\beta}= \frac{\beta^{1+\eta}}{\beta^{1+\eta} -\beta}= \frac{\beta^{\eta}}{\beta^{\eta} -1} \approx \frac{\beta^{\eta}}{\beta^{\eta} -0} \approx 1$$

but if,  $\alpha> |\beta^{1+\eta}|$ then how we extend the argument?

Note that we can not write directly $ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha -\beta}> \frac{\beta^{1+\eta}}{\beta^{1+\eta} -\beta}$ as $\alpha -\beta > \beta^{1+\eta} -\beta$

**Edit:**    Note, $\eta \leq 1/2$.

**Source of the problem :**

[image]

**Full Paper:** [linear forms in the logarithms of real algebraic numbers close to 1](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/ConfMumbaidef.pdf), *page 11*.

Comment: Then how about considering the function $f(x) = x/(x-\beta)$?

Comment: Define 'close to' $1$. Exactly how far away $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}$ is from $1$ (or at least an upper bound) will depend closely on the particular values of $\beta$ and $\eta$.

Comment: @xbh detail plz!

Comment: @Hayden Plz, check the post again, I have edited.

Comment: Why are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ supposed to form a Lucas pair? How does such a constraint play an active role in our solution?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz  you can try the general case ... also I have attached the full paper at the end.

Comment: I don't get the sentence "Observe that $\alpha/(\alpha-\beta)$ is close to $1$ when $\alpha/\beta$, ..." what does "when $\alpha/\beta$" mean? $\alpha/\beta$ isn't a condition it is just a term. Do I get something wrong?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek   I didn't get it either... to me,  it is an  incomplete sentence ...  probably  printing   mistake

Comment: Maybe this incomplete condition is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $|\beta|^\eta\gt1$, then the triangle inequality guarantees
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}-1\,\right|
&=\left|\,\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\frac1{\alpha/\beta-1}\,\right|\\
&\le\frac1{|\beta|^\eta-1}
\end{align}
$$
which is small if $|\beta|^\eta$ is large.

Comment: Note, $\eta \leq 1/2$

Comment: @MikeSQ: Okay, that doesn't affect the estimate above. We still need $|\beta|^\eta$ to be large.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac\alpha{\alpha-\beta} = 1+\frac{\beta}{\alpha -\beta}$$
with the basic error bound
$$\left|\frac\beta{\alpha-\beta}\right| \le \frac{|\beta|}{|\beta|^{1+\eta}-s|\beta|} = \frac1{|\beta|^\eta-s} \le \frac1{|\beta|^\eta - 1}$$
where $s=\pm 1$ is the sign of $\beta$.

So if at least one of $\eta>0$, and $\beta>1$ is "large enough", then $\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)$ is "close to one".

Comment: Your first equation is not right: $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}
=1+\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}$

Comment: @robjohn oops. Thanks

Comment: do u really  need s?

Comment: @MikeSQ: not if we use the triangle inequality

Comment: @MikeSQ no, but if you knew $s=-1$ then there's a slight improvement. Given that its not clear how tight a bound you want, I left it in

Answer (score 1):

In the proof of $\bf{Theorem\; 13}$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are considered integers, large enough.

$$\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}\leq \frac{1}{1-\beta^{-\eta}},$$
from where the result.

I wrote only the RHS, and this just for $\beta>0.$

Answer (score 1):

Since you have proven the inequality for $\alpha=|\beta^{1+\lambda}|$ notice that the function $\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}$ is a decreasing function of $\alpha$ when $\alpha>\beta>0$ so we have $$1<\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}<\dfrac{|\beta^{1+\lambda}|}{|\beta^{1+\lambda}|-\beta}\approx 1$$which means that $\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}$ is close to $1$ because $\dfrac{|\beta^{1+\lambda}|}{|\beta^{1+\lambda}|-\beta}$ is close to $1$

Comment: $\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta} > 1$  as  $\alpha>(\alpha-\beta)$

Comment: Yes. That's right and $\alpha\over\alpha-\beta$ is close enough to $1$ from above as I said